# Could not find or load Main class when trying to create batch file to run Java Program

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, classpath

I want to run my Java program from batch file. I got 3 jar files located in lib folder that program is using and main class is in main folder called Main. Here is batch file code that I am using

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;./lib/jcalendar-1.4.jar;./lib/forms-1.3.0.jar;./lib/mysqlconnector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar;
java main.Main
```

But when I run script I got this error: Could not find or load main class main.Main

Here is screenshot of directory where jars and batch is located
[image]

proba is batch file that I am using to run program.

Comment: Show us your source file.

Comment: Where have you kept the batch file?

Comment: it's in same folder where is folder lib and folder main @Rohit Jain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to give names of all JAR files. You can use wildcards. Apart from that, you also need to add current working directory - `.`, which contains `main.Main`, in your classpath,

You can try using this command:

```
java -cp .;./lib/* main.Main
```

Try changing your batch file content to:

```
@ECHO OFF
java -cp .;./lib/* main.Main
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Again same error display.... Added screenshot of dir. that is used fomr batch script

Comment: Is your `Main` class under `main` package?

Comment: Ok. Try first running it without the batch file. Go to `VPN` directory, and execute this command.

Comment: very nice :D @ Rohit Jain . When I run it from CMD without script it's working... I ll try to run it as administrator and will post results back

Comment: problem in Encoding (Windows Notepad). When I change it to ASCI program worked. Thank you for support. Owe you one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using -cp or -classpath switch

```
java -cp ./lib/jcalendar-1.4.jar;./lib/forms-1.3.0.jar;./lib/mysqlconnector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar;.   main.Main
```

or

```
 java -classpath ./lib/jcalendar-1.4.jar;./lib/forms-1.3.0.jar;./lib/mysqlconnector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar;.   main.Main
```

Note that the seperator differs with operating system if you are using windows use ; else use :

Comment: See the package name in your class is it correct. Which operating ?system are you using?

Comment: Everything seems to be correct, can you please share your class along with main method so that we can try at our end. Also try this: java -classpath ./lib/jcalendar-1.4.jar;./lib/forms-1.3.0.jar;./lib/mysqlconnector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar;.   main/Main